# input method of jquery not triggering in mobile devices

Tags: jquery, mobile

I have written a JQuery to hide and show a button whenever anything is entered in textbox.

JQUERY

```
$('#loan_amount').on('input', function() {
  $(".product_details").css("display", "none");
});
```

This works perfectly on desktop and mobile simulator of Chrome. But it is not working on actual mobile devices when number is inputted  using mobile keypad.
Any help would be appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Works in mobile.

Comment: Can you share the fiddle.

Comment: [check](https://jsfiddle.net/durga598/q961s57h/)

Comment: Yes working now. Don't know what was the issue. Thank you